# Stop visual studio opening layout page everytime I refresh mvc web app

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

If you create a new MVC project with all the basics it gives you (home controller, account controller, etc..), then press F5 to start it, visual studio shows the "_layout.cshtml" page in a preview window.

This gets rather frustrating if you're trying to make "on-the-fly" changes to a specific view, press F5 to refresh and see your changes, then alt-tab back to visual studio, only for it to have auto-previewed the layout page again.

How do you turn this feature off?

Comment: 6 months later, same issue

Comment: Just to add to this, I've now got it replicated on three different machines - all fresh built Win10 machines with just VS & SQL installed. Still no solution :/

Comment: VS2017 with Edge still has the same behaviour. So I reported this problem to Microsoft here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80226/vs2017-previews-layoutcshtml-when-debugging-aspnet.html

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio, you should disable the checkbox for 'Enable browser link'.
[image]

Comment: Uhh, *the* checkbox???  Where is this check box among a million others?

Comment: Cool - thanks so much - I never would have found it!

Comment: This should be selected answer. None of the other scenarios in answers and comments were true for me. I was seeing this behavior while running Selenium tests using the ChromeDriver. I don't even have FireFox installed.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce on a new install. For me, the offender was "Web Essentials" extension. Try to disable and restart VS.
Also, it only happens with Edge's developer tools open. Haven't seen this with Firefox nor Chrome.

Comment: That indeed makes the difference - stopping "Web Essentials" does stop the behaviour, however that's only half way home, as I need "Web Essentials" to actually be turned on.
If you can work out what it is in "Web Essentials" that causes it, or a suitable workaround that keeps the addon enabled, but stops the behaviour, I'll give you the accepted answer!

Comment: Try Options -> Web Essentials -> Browser Link -> Enable f12 auto-sync = false.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this without web essentials tab being installed. 
 In my case, `_layout.cshtml` file opens after I run the solution in debug mode (F5).  After that if I press F12 to open developer tools in IE or Edge the layout page opens because Dev Tool auto highlights the first line of HTML in the `<body>` tag which is my layout.cshtml file.  It has always frustrated me and I can't find a solution either.

Comment: To confirm, I'm still also having the problem, despite web essentials being removed :/

Comment: yes that is the cause, in EDGE, just close the dev tool, and this behavior stops, yes its CRAZY irritating, thanks @ober for sharing the solution

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the `F12 Developer Tools` where the page of the selected element in the `DOM Explorer`/`Elements` tab is automatically opened and synchronized in Visual Studio.

If you want to keep the `Browser Link` feature enabled, the `F12 Developer Tools` window open, and not lose your currently focused tab in Visual Studio, here's a work-around:
1. Right-click on the `_Layout.cshtml` tab in Visual Studio and select `New Vertical Tab Group`.
If you already have a tab group open, select `Move to Next Tab Group`.
2. Resize the splitter control of the tab group so that the tab group is barely visible.
3. Repeat these steps for all other files that automatically open in Visual Studio which disrupt your workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate your exact problem, but the following should disable the preview tab:

1. Type "preview" into Quick Launch
2. Select "Environment --> Tabs and Windows"
3. Disable "Allow new files to be opened in the preview tab"

[image]

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, and I'm afraid it doesn't stop it.

Comment: In the properties of the layout file, what is the build action?

Comment: build action = Content

Comment: Another long shot: Have you tried resetting the Visual Studio settings? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: sadly yes.. again to no avail :/